# Where can I find.NET Configuration Tool?

Tags: .net

I want to use code access security and add code modify group. but I don't see the .NET Configuration Tool in Administrator Tools.

Where can I find this tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been retired, the last version I know shipped with the .NET 2.0 SDK around the VS2005 time frame.  No loss btw, it wasn't a great tool.  You now need to use the Caspol.exe command line tool, run it from the Visual Studio Command Prompt or directly from the framework directory (c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727 for example).  Run caspol /? for very basic command line argument help, docs [are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz%28VS.80%29.aspx).